# How to make a memcpy inside of an thread of pthread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to do a sum of 2 matrices using pthreads in c++. I'm stuck at trying to pass the result of the sum calculated inside a thread to my main function.

The 2 values to be added are inside a struct:

```
struct sum{
    int value1;
    int value2;
    int result;
}typedef struct_sum;
```

And the struct containing the values is passed as an argument to `pthread_create()` so that the operation is excuted inside a thread.

Here's my routine:

```
void * routine(void * sum) {
    std::cout<<((struct_sum *)sum)->value1 + ((struct_sum *)sum)->value2<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<((struct_sum *)sum)->value1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<((struct_sum *)sum)->value2<<std::endl;
    int i = (((struct_sum *) sum)->value1 + ((struct_sum *) sum)->value2);
//    memcpy(&(((struct_sum *)sum)->result), reinterpret_cast<const void *>(i), sizeof(i));
    ((struct_sum *)sum)->result = i;
    std::cout<<&(((struct_sum *)sum)->result)<<std::endl;
    pthread_exit(nullptr);
}
```

In the first 3 `cout` I check if my values are coming correctly to the thread.
In the last `cout` (before exiting the thread) I check the memory address of the result element of the struct (so I can see that it has the same address inside the main function).

Here's the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int mat_1[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {{1, 2},
                                        {6, 7}};
    int mat_2[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {{3, 15},
                                        {9, 14}};
    int mat_result[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];
    int mat_size = sizeof(mat_1) / sizeof(int);
    int row_size = sizeof(mat_1) / sizeof(mat_1[0]);
    int column_size = sizeof(mat_1[0]) / sizeof(int);
    pthread_t threads[mat_size];
    int thread_number = 0;
    int thread_handler;
    for (int row = 0; row < row_size; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < column_size; column++) {
            struct_sum *result;
            result = static_cast<struct_sum *>(malloc(sizeof(struct_sum)));
            result->value1 = mat_1[row][column];
            result->value2 = mat_2[row][column];
            result->result = 0;
            thread_handler = pthread_create(&threads[thread_number], nullptr, routine, result);
            if(thread_handler) return(-1);
            std::cout << &(result->result)<<std::endl;
            thread_number++;
            mat_result[row][column] = result->result;
//            free(result);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(nullptr);
}
```

I'm having two problems:

1. Even though the result has the same address in the main and in the thread, when I copy the value of `i` to `((struct_sum *)sum)->result`, in the `main` function, `result->result` is still 0.
2. When I uncomment the `memcpy()` line the thread simply don't run, so I don't know how I'm doing it wrong.

I was expecting that in my `main` function the statement `std::cout << (result->result) <<std::endl` would return me the result of the operation, but the current value is 0.

So, how do I perform the `memcpy()` correctly in the thread?

Comment: You haven’t waited on any of the threads to finish (or do anything at all).

Comment: How do I wait then?

Comment: Also, why don't you use any of std multi-threading library? Plus what's with all the c-style coding? If you used `std::thread` you would instantly notice that there is a problem as you would get a throw - since none of your threads finished their execution.

Comment: Sincerely, because I used my professor's example of pthread, so I didnt want to change the library he used in class

Comment: Once it works, please take your code to codereview.stackexchange.com. There are many bit and pieces that could and should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to JOIN your threads. It means, wait them to finish.
The way you were doing is basically starting the thread and not giving it a guaranteed time do to anything. Besides that, some important change to the API, check the comments below:

```
void * routine(void * sum) {
    int i = (((struct_sum *) sum)->value1 + ((struct_sum *) sum)->value2);
    ((struct_sum *)sum)->result = i;

    // notice you don't need memcpy(), in fact...
    // but you could use it here if you want... it won't fail.

    // you have to use this function so it return your result to the main thread.
    pthread_exit(sum);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int mat_1[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {{1, 2},
                                        {6, 7}};
    int mat_2[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {{3, 15},
                                        {9, 14}};
    int mat_result[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];
    int mat_size = sizeof(mat_1) / sizeof(int);
    int row_size = sizeof(mat_1) / sizeof(mat_1[0]);
    int column_size = sizeof(mat_1[0]) / sizeof(int);
    pthread_t threads[mat_size];
    int thread_number = 0;
    int thread_handler;
    for (int row = 0; row < row_size; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < column_size; column++) {
            struct_sum *result;
            result = static_cast<struct_sum *>(malloc(sizeof(struct_sum)));
            result->value1 = mat_1[row][column];
            result->value2 = mat_2[row][column];
            result->result = 0;
            thread_handler = pthread_create(&threads[thread_number], nullptr, routine, result);
            if(thread_handler) return(-1);
            // std::cout << &(result->result)<<std::endl;
            thread_number++;
            // forget this line below
            // mat_result[row][column] = result->result;
        }
    }

    // here you wait for the threads to JOIN
    // here it means they actually "finished" their job
    for (int i = 0; i < mat_size; i++)
    {
        struct_sum *result;

        // here you wait for the threads to finish their job
        // add something to your struct to "identify" the thread, so
        // you can figure out where in the final matrix you put the result
        pthread_join(threads[i], (void**)&result);
        std::cout << result->result << "\n";

        // this will print the correct sums: 4, 17, 15 and 21
        // notice: it will be printed in ANY order, once you
        // don't know which thread will finish first
        // but result->result has the... result you need!
        // you have to figure out how to fit this result in your matrix.
        // but this is out of scope of the question
        // and you can do yourself. have fun! :-)

        // here you can free the result, you already got the value!
        free(result);
    }

    // you don't need this line below... this goes to routine()
    // pthread_exit(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```